# Ensure double binding sync

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've the following setup with Angular 1.0.7:

I've a directive which is mean to display styled checkbox.

[See plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Al5cEu5WDs7ZwxZpk9wO?p=preview).

- `All` must toggle `Foo` and `Bar`
- if `Foo` and `Bar` are truthy, `All` should be truthy.
- if `Foo` or `Bar` is falsy, `All` should be falsy.

[here is a failing situation](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s244/sh/507b1a5b-7cf5-4ea6-88f9-8f10edd3765b/44c3864a687da2ccda91479682c3fd7d) which sometimes happens. and I'd like to understand why.

Comment: Have you tried doing a `$watch` within the directive link function? Also, this needs a bit more code to get some context. Can you put up a jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: adding a `$watch` in the directive feels weird: isnt the `=` supposed to handle it out of the box? I could try to create a plunkr but the `sometimes` could not happen (even if its pretty clear for me in my browser).

Comment: using $watch isn't weird. But again a plunkr would help.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. In first part you're explaining the process in which the `foo` gets updated when directive changes `bar`, but in second part you say something opposite: "_...the directive sometimes fails to update according to the new value of foo_". I think Plunker is a must here.

Comment: ok guys, here you go: http://plnkr.co/edit/Al5cEu5WDs7ZwxZpk9wO?p=preview

Comment: and example of failing situation: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s244/sh/507b1a5b-7cf5-4ea6-88f9-8f10edd3765b/44c3864a687da2ccda91479682c3fd7d

Comment: do you need to use version 1.0.7 ? Upgrades allow  template as function

Comment: yes I need to, hopefully i can upgrade later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that works great in 1.1.5 and up . I wrapped checkbox in a `<label>` to take advantage of native click of checkbox and added `ng-change` to checkbox. Removed all jQuery usage and used `$broadcast` and `$on`. I also added one extra attribute to the `toggleAll`... `attrs.master`

```
app.directive("uuCheckbox", function($rootScope) {

    return {
      restrict: "A",
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      template:function(elem,tAttrs){
        var name;
        name = tAttrs.name ? "name='" + tAttrs.name + "'" : '';

        return "<label class='styledui'>" + 
              "<span class='custom checkbox' ng-class='{ checked: model }'></span>" + 
              "<input class='hidden' value='true' type='checkbox' ng-model='model' " + " " + name + " ng-change='checkToggle()'/>" + 
            "<span ng-class='{red: model}' ng-transclude></span>" + "</label>";

      },
      scope: {
        model: '='
      },

      link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
        if(attrs.master){

          scope.$on('slaveChanged',function(event, slaveModel){
            if(scope.model && !slaveModel){
              scope.model=false;
            }
          })
        }else{
          scope.$on('ToggleAll',function(event, toggle){
            scope.model=toggle
          });
        }

        scope.checkToggle=function(){
          if(attrs.master){
            $rootScope.$broadcast('ToggleAll', scope.model)
          }else{
            $rootScope.$broadcast('slaveChanged', scope.model)
          }
        }

      }
    };
  });
```

I tried reverse engineering it to `1.0.7` and ran out of time. Older $compile docs are hard to find now

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/9nul5rKnEEK69Kvj5mJr?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: same issue :) https://www.evernote.com/shard/s244/sh/289ff6f7-f4a4-4cc4-a944-5f878872ee34/69171a5e26ad8753bd8db47d73b12294

Comment: ok is that from case of manually selecting individuals...then if all are manually selected `toggleAll` goes red? If so will either nead an array to loop over... or traverse DOM to check if all are manually selected

Comment: yes manually selected. Watchers are already in place but they sometimes fails... that's the whole point of my question: why sometimes it works, why sometimes it fails?

Comment: btw, +1 for your efforts

Comment: thanks but: I use 1.0.7 and the checkbox directive is used for all checkboxes on the website, that's why I dont want events but rather callbacks.

Comment: events are available in 1.0.7, only big difference is I used `template:function()` which only accepted string then ( not function)

Comment: I know events are available but I dont want them: all my checkboxes use the same directive, my real question is why: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s244/sh/2ce8f2ec-cb71-4a77-9164-2c53e5a3b606/d511213dc6b5f278aac6145bbc0e1f5a

Comment: well, I ended up opening another more detailed question. Let's close this one and accept your answer even if it's not what I expect :)